# AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am new to tensorflow I was tring to use tf.concat so I used this layout instead of the regular Sequential layout. But the error I get is AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
The error exists in the 2nd line

```
inp = Input(shape=(1050,1050,3))
x1= layers.Conv2D(16 ,(3,3), activation='relu')(inp)
x1= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
x1= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x1)
x2= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
x2= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x2)
x2= layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3)(x2)
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(2,2), activation='relu')(x3)
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x3)
x3= layers.Dropout(0.2)(x3)
x3= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x3)
x4= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')
x4= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x4)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x4)
o = layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([x1, x2, x3, x4, x])
y = layers.Flatten()(o)
y = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(y)
y = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(y) 

model = Model(inp, y)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The imported files are

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import keras_preprocessing
from keras_preprocessing import image
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input
```

The error is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-40840424e579> in <module>
      1 inp = Input(shape=(1050,1050,3))
----> 2 x1= layers.Conv2D(16 ,(3,3), activation='relu')(inp)
      3 x1= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
      4 x1= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x1)
      5 x2= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    661               kwargs.pop('training')
    662             inputs, outputs = self._set_connectivity_metadata_(
--> 663                 inputs, outputs, args, kwargs)
    664           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    665           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, previous_mask)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _set_connectivity_metadata_(self, inputs, outputs, args, kwargs)
   1706     kwargs.pop('mask', None)  # `mask` should not be serialized.
   1707     self._add_inbound_node(
-> 1708         input_tensors=inputs, output_tensors=outputs, arguments=kwargs)
   1709     return inputs, outputs
   1710 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _add_inbound_node(self, input_tensors, output_tensors, arguments)
   1793     """
   1794     inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
-> 1795                                         input_tensors)
   1796     node_indices = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.node_index,
   1797                                       input_tensors)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    513 
    514   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 515       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    516       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    517 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    513 
    514   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 515       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    516       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    517 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in <lambda>(t)
   1792             `call` method of the layer at the call that created the node.
   1793     """
-> 1794     inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
   1795                                         input_tensors)
   1796     node_indices = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.node_index,

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

Please Anyone tell me What to Do
The Code is little changed than before Please take a look again

Comment: As suggested in the answer to above question, you need to wrap `tf.concat()` inside a `Lambda` layer. Alternatively, you can use `keras.layers.concatenate(...)` to do the concatenation.

Comment: Also you need to have actual input layers, currently the input is a Conv2D.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the error shows in the 2nd line

Comment: Yes, so? The problem is still the same, you cannot give a non-Input layer as input to another layer in the Functional API.

Comment: Can you explain then what is should do

Comment: Acutally I am new to tensorflow(and ML)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Then how ca n i give that non-input layer as input

Comment: Can you add the full imports to yourcode?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes I did

Comment: You are mixing tf.keras and keras imports, you should never do that, those libraries are not compatible to each other. You are importing Layer from keras and the other layers from tf.keras

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Ya I am sorry But now i used from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input instead of the keras one , now it worked thanks But a new error pops that is entirely new error thanks for the help till now

Comment: The new error can be found in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542946/valueerror-a-concatenate-layer-requires-inputs-with-matching-shapes-except-fo

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to pass x2 an input argument in the fourth line, also same with x3 and x4. So instead of writing

```
x2= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')
```

You should have

```
x2= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to instance a `Input` layer to give the input to your first layer:

```
inp = Input(shape=(1050,1050,3))
x1= layers.Conv2D(16 ,(3,3), activation='relu')(inp)
x1= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
x1= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x1)
x2= layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu')(x1)
x2= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x2)
x2= layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3)(x2)
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x2)
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(2,2), activation='relu')(x3)
x3= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x3)
x3= layers.Dropout(0.2)(x3)
x3= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x3)
x4= layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu')(x3)
x4= layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x4)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x4)
o = layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([x1, x2, x3, x4, x])
y = layers.Flatten()(o)
y = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(y)
y = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(y) 

model = Model(inp, y)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As mentioned in the other answer, you also did not pass the correct input to one of the `Conv2D` layers. And you cannot use `tf` functions directly on Keras tensors, Keras already has a layer to perform concatenation.

Comment: A new error appears on the 2nd line AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'

Comment: @Lawlesx Please add the whole traceback, an error message in isolation is meaningless.

Comment: @Lawlesx I cannot reproduce the error with the given code (I get other errors, but not the one you mention in that line). Please provide self-containing example that reproduces the error and we can run.

Comment: I didn't get what self-containing examples but i did add the imported files required